# MappingException: InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, dozer

I have a small problem here and hope that someone can help me out.

I wanna do a mapping from Object to Integer. The Object is marked as Fetchtype.Lazy.

When I do the mapping I get the following error message:

```
11:31:46,569 ERROR MappingProcessor:253 - Field mapping error -->
  MapId: null
  Type: null
  Source parent class: ClassA
  Source field name: MyObjectProperty
  Source field type: null
  Source field value: null
  Dest parent class: ClassB
  Dest field name: myIntegerProperty
  Dest field type: java.lang.Integer
org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:88)
    at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:258)
    at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.invokeReadMethod(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:234)
    at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getPropertyValue(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.getSrcFieldValue(FieldMap.java:82)
```

InnerException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to access an unloaded field of detached instance
```

I created a custom converter in dozer xml file but the converter is never called. I guess the application gets a problem before reaching this converter.

Funny thing is I can Map the fields successfully the other way around, so Integer to Object.

I appreciate any ideas, if you need further information please give me a word.

Thx to all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this were Hibernate I'd think a lazily loaded field were accessed outside of the Session the data bean is bound to.

I suggest loading the entity and mapping it in the same transaction would solve the problem. I don't know that for sure of course :)

Comment: Yeah you were right I put @Transactional over the method and it works now. Thank you very much